# spring data jpa - Parameter value [Book] did not match expected type [ContentType]

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have two simple tables, `content` and `contentType`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content implements Serializable {

public Content() {}

public Content(String title, String description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
private ContentCategory contentCategory;

@ManyToOne
private ContentType contentType;

 // getter/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "contentType")
public class ContentType implements Serializable {

public ContentType() {}

public ContentType(String contentType) {
    this.contentType = contentType;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;

@NotNull
private String contentType;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contentType")
private Set<Content> content;
`// getter/setters` }
```

`Each content has exactly one type, but many type might be exists in many contents`

I am going to retrieve contents with type `Book`

Here is my repository"

```
public interface ContentRepository extends JpaRepository<Content, Long> {

    Iterable<Content> findByContentType(String contentType);
}
```

And Here is my test method:

```
@Test
public void retrieve_content_based_on_type() {

    // create and insert a sample content type, i.e. a Book

    ContentType contentType1 = new ContentType("Book");
    contentTypeRepository.save(contentType1);

    //create and insert two contents corresponding to this type
    Content cont1 = new Content("t1", "d1");
    cont1.setContentType(contentType1);
    contentRepository.save(cont1);

    Content cont2 = new Content("t2", "d2");
    cont2.setContentType(contentType1);
    contentRepository.save(cont2);


    //retrieve all contents which their type is Book

    Iterable<Content> allBooks = contentRepository.findByContentType("Book");
    for (Content eachBook : allBooks) {
        System.out.println(eachBook);
    }
}
```

I got this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [Book] did not match expected type [com.aa.bb.domain.ContentType (n/a)]; 

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Book] did not match expected type [com.aa.bb.domain.ContentType (n/a)]
```

Comment: ContentType contentType1 = new ContentType("Book"); you don't have parameterised constructor in ContentType Class

Comment: @zombie Sorry, see again the content type constructor.

Comment: You are passing in a `String` which should be a `ContentType` instead. Either change your method signature to use a `ContentType` or change the mapping to a `String.

Comment: What is this line Content cont1 = new Content("t1", "d1") , you dont have any String propertis in your Content class.

Comment: @M.Deinum See the `Content` second constructor

Comment: That doesn't matter, the type of the field matters and that is `ContentType`. So either make it a `String` in the `Content` class (as that is what you query) or create a custom query for it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I can't change it to `String` , so i have to use custom query, here is my custom query: `@Query("from Content c where c.ContentType.contentType = :contentType")` .

But i get compile error in word `from` !

Comment: Now you don't have to use a custom query you need to change the `String` to a `ContentType` in your method. The types have to match.

Comment: Your query needs to start with `select c` and not `from`. Also `c.ContentType.contentType` will not work, the property is named `ContentType` in your `Content` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify your current method to this:

```
@Query("select c from Content c where c.contentType.contentType = :contentType")
Iterable<Content> findByContentType(String contentType);
```

Reason: the contentType in Content entity is of type ContentType whereas in ContentType entity it is of type String

In terms of Spring Data JPA without using query annotation, following is the solution:

```
Iterable<Content> findByContentTypeContentType(String contentType);
```

Spring Data Reference [Link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Above method is for Repository class ContentRepository.

Comment: can you provide the error info?
Did you try the other one ...without using query annotation

Comment: I'm using `IDEA` for IDE

Comment: i have made the select also explicit...try this. For me the earlier one has worked in my use cases. not sure why it is not working in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
 public interface ContentRepository extends JpaRepository<Content, Long> 
 {
    Iterable<Content> findByContentType(String contentType);
  }
```

To:

```
 public interface ContentRepository extends JpaRepository<ContentType , Long> 
   {
  Iterable<ContentType > findByContentType(String contentType);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try changing the variable name to something else in the ContentType class.

```
private String contentType;
```